# Access methods coming from props inside map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following two components `App.js` and `PersonalInfo.js`:

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import PersonalInfo from "./PersonalInfo";

class App extends Component {
  state = [{ fname: "Jonny", lname: "Deep" }, { fname: "test", lname: "test" }];

  inputChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PersonalInfo
          data={this.state}
          inputChangeHandler={this.inputChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**PersonalInfo.js**

```js
import React from "react";

const PersonalInfo = props => {
  const test = props.data.map((x, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="form-row align-items-center">
        <div className="col-sm-3 my-1">
          <label className="sr-only">First Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="inlineFormInputName"
            name="fname"
            value={x.fname}
            onChange={props.inputChangeHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-3 my-1">
          <label className="sr-only">Last Name</label>
          <div className="input-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername"
              name="lname"
              value={x.lname}
              onChange={props.inputChangeHandler}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-auto my-1">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Add
          </button>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger">
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form>{test}</form>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(props, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PersonalInfo;
```

With the above code I'm getting error of **props.data.map is not a function** when I type in the input field. If I comment out or remove  `onChange={props.inputChangeHandler}` it works. But `onChange` to update the state.

How do I remove the error  and make it work ?

Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-leakey-ub859?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what is your blueprint? you want to render every data with input?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make  a form where we can add and remove input fields.

Comment: I mean, do you need many input fields? or one field

Comment: Oh sorry. Just one at the start. I added another to the test.

Comment: I don't understand why you need multiple inputs form.

Comment: Long story man. Just help me to get over this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputChangeHandler is wrong, your updating an array using an object. So when you call it your array became an object like this { key: value }.

To achieve your goal you'll need a unique ID to easily find your data inside your array and then you need to modify this array :

```js
state = [{ id: 1, fname: "Jonny", lname: "Deep" }, { id: 2, fname: "test", lname: "test" }]

inputChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
  this.setState((prev) => {
    const indexOfName = prev.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
    prev[indexOfName][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    return prev;
  })
}
```

And you need also to change the way you call it :

```js
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="inlineFormInputName"
            name="fname"
            value={x.fname}
            onChange={(event) => props.inputChangeHandler(event, x.id)}
          />
```

I made a small working example using the index instead of id : https://codesandbox.io/embed/nifty-napier-ps86v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Is there a way without id ??

Comment: Maybe just using the index with the map function can do the work, so instead of using id you can use the value of i `` props.data.map((x, i) => ``

Comment: @PawanRai here is a working exemple with the index https://codesandbox.io/embed/nifty-napier-ps86v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark